# how to make multi language site in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, multilingual

I wanted to make a wordpress website in 2 languages. English and Arabic. I wanted to make pages, categories and menus in 2 languages when user select English only English pages will shown to the user and when select Arabic only Arabic pages,categories and menus will be shown. ONLY Posts will remain the same for both. Every thing except posts will be changed user user.

Comment: I think you should take this to [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Get the the language pack (e.g. `de_DE.mo`) from [wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language). If the language pack isn't available as a standalone download, you could also use the `.mo` file which is bundled in the WordPress ZIP-file for your language. Located under `wp-content/languages`.
2. Move the `.mo` file to `wp-content/languages/` of your default (english) WordPress installation.
3. Change the `WPLANG` constant in `wp-config.php` to the new locale (e.g. `de_DE`)
4. In your `functions.php` add the following filter:

**functions.php**

```
add_filter('locale', 'wpse27056_setLocale');
function wpse27056_setLocale($locale) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }

    return $locale;
}
```

**Reference** - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/different-language-for-frontend-and-backend

Take a look at WordPress Codex - **[Translating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)**

Additionally you can use WP plugins especially for translating your WP website: 
**[Codestyling Localization](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/)** 
**[User Language Switch](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-language-switch/)**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look about for a plugin that would do this for you.

I would say WPML plugin would be prefect for what you are trying to do, but this is a premium plugin and costs http://wpml.org .

Answer (score 0):

hi M Usman Tahir i already work on 3 website that has multilangauge

follow the to see www.decidact.com

this website is in 5 language

1)download [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/)  plugind for  your post content
2)downlaod [codingstylelocalization](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/) for caption tranlsation